# oracle SQL substring between two strings with multiple lines and XML

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm looking for a string between 2 other strings with XML encoding surrounding it and the string to be extracted from a field with 2 lines.

I want to have the number `7,5` between `attr4">` and `</attr>` (and then also the number `3,5` in the second line)

```
Line 1: <attr name="attr1; attr2; attr3; attr4">7,5</attr>
Line 2: <attr name="attr5; attr6; attr7; attr8">3,5</attr>
```

attr4 can contain round brackets. E.g. 'attribute (m)'

I don't really understand the syntax of regexp. So I also tried substr and with a with-clause, but it also yields NULL.

I tried (e.g.):

```
SELECT substr( match, 2, length(match)-2 ) from (
SELECT regexp_substr('<attr name="attr1; attr2; attr3; attr4">7,5</attr>
<attr name="attr5; attr6; attr7; attr8">3,5</attr>', '\:(.+)\~') match FROM dual);
```

Expected result: 7,5.

It looked quite simple, but a few hours later and trying solutions from other posts I haven't got anywhere yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. Use a proper XML parser.

You only have a fragment of XML and need to wrap it in a single parent node but once you have done that, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/root/attr'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(
           '<root>' || '<attr name="attr1; attr2; attr3; attr4">7,5</attr>
<attr name="attr5; attr6; attr7; attr8">3,5</attr>' || '</root>'
         )
         COLUMNS
           names VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './@name',
           value VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './text()'
       )
```

Which outputs:

| NAMES | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| attr1; attr2; attr3; attr4 | 7,5 |
| attr5; attr6; attr7; attr8 | 3,5 |

*Note: If you are only interested in the `value` column then you do not need to extract the `name` attribute as well.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BXpl_HUE)